# Добавить атрибут в ActiveRecord Yii2/ отобразить произвольные данные в GridView::widget

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Вывод данных в виде происходит через GridView::widget
Задача стояла подсветить определенные колонки если есть совпадение по параметрам.
Сделал логику в контроллере передаю в вид отдельным массивом нужные данные.
Как бы не старался их не видно.
В модели атрибут заводил в него передавал методом $model->custom_attr = $value;,
так же делал геттер и сеттер, все одно.
В GridView::widget $model->custom_attr равно NULL.
Как сделать так, чтобы созданный атрибут попал в ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private] или как передать свои данные в GridView::widget, которых нет в модели, но они переданны в вид в виде переменной?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

определите в модели метод getMyField()
в GridView обращайтесь к атрибуту myField

в нотации модели можно еще указать

```
/**@property string myField*/
```

что бы получить подсказки шторма, или какая у вас среда разработки.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.
Но я так делал, не помогает. Я устанавливаю значение атрибута в _action'не_ контроллера. Во _view_ если вызвать передаваемую модель, значение можно использовать, но в _GridView::widget_ оно равно _NULL_

Comment: Прикрутил решение на js

Comment: можно через анонимную функцию и замыкание в gridView  `function($model) use ($youVariable) {return $some; }` а контроллере логику вообще держать фу фу фу

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду стараться :)